# How to capture multiple instances of a pattern between two other patterns

Tags: regex, ruby

I have string like:

```
starta.sdf.adf..awefw.d.e$5.00ejfae.fmaf$25.00adsfendlkafeeeeeeji$50.00awef
```

and I need to extract the dollar amounts between `start` and `end`.

Using `(?:.+?\$(\d+\.\d{2}))` gives me all of the amounts, including the one after `end` which I don't want.

Changing the regex to `(?:.+?\$(\d+\.\d{2})).+end` makes so only one instance is captured.

Adding a plus after the capture group like: `(?:.+?\$(\d+\.\d{2}))+.+end` does not seem to change anything and repeat the pattern as I expect.

The expected result is:

```
0: 5.00
1: 25.00
```

How can I capture multiple instances of this pattern between the start and end patterns?

Comment: A really good starting point is, WHY do you have a string like that? It looks like corrupted data, so perhaps if we straighten that out the rest will fall into place easily. So, how are you gathering the data? See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)".

Comment: Just so you know, technically, your question isn't asked well and can be voted down or closed. You need to show us your attempt to solve it, and include the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you're having. "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages explain it.

Comment: You can easily do that with a single pattern if the start and end delimiters are different strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd  do something like this:

```
foo = "starta.sdf.adf..awefw.d.e$5.00ejfae.fmaf$25.00adsfendlkafeeeeeeji$50.00awef"
foo[/start.+end/].scan(/\$[\d.]+/)
# => ["$5.00", "$25.00"]
```

Breaking it down a bit:

```
foo[/start.+end/]    # => "starta.sdf.adf..awefw.d.e$5.00ejfae.fmaf$25.00adsfend"
   .scan(/\$[\d.]+/) # => ["$5.00", "$25.00"]
```

I'd restrict the range using a small pattern, then grab the values. Trying to do it in one pattern is silly and harder to do. `foo[/start.+end/]` is a [String slice, using a pattern](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Regular expressions are extremely powerful, but people try to do too much in them sometimes and disappear down a rabbit hole, when, instead, if they broke the problem into smaller pieces they'd be easily solved.

If you don't want the leading dollar-sign, there are many ways to strip it, here are two:

```
foo[/start.+end/].scan(/\$[\d.]+/).map { |s| s.delete('$') } # => ["5.00", "25.00"]
foo[/start.+end/].scan(/\$[\d.]+/).map { |s| s[1..-1] }      # => ["5.00", "25.00"]
```

But, the input string is really unusual, and smells like data gone wild. I suspect it's binary data you're not processing correctly.

Comment: Also `\K` can be used to remove the dollar sign: `foo[/start.+end/].scan(/\$\K[\d.]+/)`

Comment: I haven't seen the foo[/start.+end/] syntax before. What is it called?

Comment: See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D. It's a "slice" using a pattern.